# What is the difference between React component instance property and state property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the below example

```
class MyApp extends Component {
    counter = 0;
    state = {
        counter: 0
    };
    incrementCounter() {
        this.counter = this.counter + 1;
        this.setState({
            counter: this.state.counter + 1
        });
    }
    render() {
        return <div>
            <p>{this.counter} and {this.state.counter}</p>
            <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>Increment</button>
        </div>
    }
}
```

When I click the button I see both this.counter and this.state.counter are showing the incremented value

My question is why I have to use state? though react is capable of re-rendering all the instance properties

```
counter = 0;
incrementCounter() {
    this.counter = this.counter + 1;
    this.setState({});
}
```

In above snippet, just calling this.setState({}) is doing the trick, then why should I use this.state property for storing my component state?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`state` and `instance properties` serve different purposes. While calling setState with empty arguments will cause a render and will reflect the updated instance properties, state can be used for many more features like
comparing `prevState` and `currentState` in shouldComponentUpdate to decide whether you want to render or not, or in lifecycle method like componentDidUpdate where you can take an action based on state change.

state is a special instance property used by react to serve special purposes. Also in `setState`, state updates are batched for performance reasons and state updates happen asynchronously unlike class variable updates which happen synchronously. A class variable won't have these features.

Also when you supply a class variable as prop to the component, a change in this class variable can't be differentiated in the lifecycle methods of the child component unless you are creating a new instance of the variable yourself. React does it with `state` property for you already.

Comment: This answer does a good job at explaining the uses and bwnefits of state, but it makes it sound like instance variables should never be used. Might be worth including a note about how instance variously are set synchronously while state variables are set asychronously. In some situations, it can be very useful to be able to set a property sychronously. One example that comes to mind is animation interrupts. Or, if you are tracking the cursor/touch point position, etc...

Answer (score 11):

Both have different purpose. Rule of thumb is:

- Use `state` to store data if it is involved in rendering or data flow (i.e. if its used directly or indirectly in render method)
- Use `other instance fields` to store data if value is **NOT** involved in rendering or data flow (to prevent rendering on change of data) e.g. to store a timer ID that is not used in render method. See [TimerID example](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) in official docs to understand this valid case.

> If some value isn’t used for rendering or data flow (for example, a timer ID), you don’t have
>   to put it in the state. Such values can be defined as fields on the
>   component instance.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state